# Calculating sum of total values from mycursor loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am not quite sure how to calculate the grand total of all items, I want to find the sum of "Total product value" for each item. Do i need to make it a variable or is there another way to do it?

```
 /* DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total product value: ' || (s_QtyExpected + s_QtyHand) 
    * s_ItemRate); */ 

-------
    DECLARE
    CURSOR myCursor IS SELECT Ship_ID, Date_Arrive, Qty_expected, Description, 
    Qty_Hand, Item_Rate
    FROM SampleData;
    s_ShipID NUMBER (5) := &shipID;
    s_DateArrival DATE;
    s_QtyExpected NUMBER (4);
    s_Description VARCHAR2 (20);
    s_QtyHand NUMBER (4);
    s_ItemRate NUMBER (6,3);
    BEGIN
    OPEN mycursor;
    LOOP
      FETCH mycursor INTO s_ShipID, s_DateArrival, s_QtyExpected, s_Description, 
    s_QtyHand, s_ItemRate;
      EXIT WHEN mycursor%NOTFOUND; 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Shipment ' || s_ShipID || ' is expected to arrive on 
    ' || s_DateArrival || '.');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Description: ' || s_Description);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Shipment value: ' || s_QtyExpected * s_ItemRate);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Quantity on Hand: ' || s_QtyHand);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total product value: ' || (s_QtyExpected + s_QtyHand) 
    * s_ItemRate);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE myCursor;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('GRAND TOTAL VALUE OF ALL ITEMS:');
    END; 
    /
```

Comment: Is this a homework and you have to do it in PL / SQL using a cursor ? Usually such calculations are much easier to do using ordinary SQL query, without PL/SQL and cursors.

Answer (score 0):

It is just what Krokodillo wrote. Usually it is done with a query. 
However it can also be done with a procedure.
I guess that there are more than one records because you use a loop.

If the "Qty_expected" and "Qty_Hand" depend on the ship_Id the you can use the next query:

```
select ship_id, sum((s_QtyExpected + s_QtyHand) * s_ItemRate)
from sampledata
group by ship_id;
```

Or you can use the for loop (then you do not need anymore then "exit when.." construction, because when the last record of the cursor has being processed then loop automatically stops.

```
declare
  CURSOR myCursor 
  IS 
  SELECT Ship_ID, Date_Arrive, Qty_expected, Description, 
         Qty_Hand, Item_Rate
  FROM SampleData;

  s_ShipID NUMBER (5) := &shipID;
  s_DateArrival DATE;
  s_QtyExpected NUMBER (4);
  s_Description VARCHAR2 (20);
  s_QtyHand NUMBER (4);
  s_ItemRate NUMBER (6,3);

  ln_grand_total    number;

BEGIN 

  for row in mycursor
  loop

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Shipment ' || row.s_ShipID || ' is expected to arrive on 
' || row.s_DateArrival || '.');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Description: ' || row.s_Description);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Shipment value: ' || row.s_QtyExpected * row.s_ItemRate);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Quantity on Hand: ' || row.s_QtyHand);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total product value: ' || (row.s_QtyExpected + row.s_QtyHand) * row.s_ItemRate);

    ln_grand_total := ln_grand_total + (row.s_QtyExpected + row.s_QtyHand) * row.s_ItemRate;

  end loop;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('GRAND TOTAL VALUE OF ALL ITEMS:'||ln_grand_total);

end;
```

I hope that this will help you.

Comment: I am getting an error. PLS-00302: component 'S_SHIPID' must be declared. For all of the declarations